# Git error when trying to Merge from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, merge

I keep getting this error while trying to merge a branch with the master branch.
I edit the same file on both branches.

> . Detailed message: Could not rmdir
>   'C:/Source/Repos/repoTest2/slnFolder/projectFolder/': Access is
>   denied.

and then the file which was changed in both branches is deleted (appears in changes)

important facts:

1. I am new to git
2. windows 10
3. .Net 4.5
4. "run as administrator" didnt help
5. when using other git gui (source tree, git gui) it works greate - but it is not an option for long term
6. it is a big project which was created in VS2013 few years ago. (when i created a small new console application and try to do the same thing, it worked great)
7. I use standard vs gitignore file

thank you !

---

**Problem Solved!**
I manually created the directories tree and copy all the files.
(another option is to delete the local repository and clone the remote one)

Comment: the only important fact really is that you (or the account that the process doing the deletion is running as) don't have permission to delete that folder

Comment: @ADyson How can I check which account is running the deletion? 
how can I change it? Why is it different from other gui?

Answer (score 0):

**Merge Branches:**

You don't need to edit the same file on both the branches. Don't edit in Master Branch. Just create PR(Pull Request) for other branch to merge with Master.

It looks like you don't have permission for file/folder that you are trying to delete.
Get complete access to that repository for merging.